# jQuery GUID as string and "Syntax error, unrecognized expression"

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to identify an HTML element using a GUID from the item in a database.

I have a GUID from SQL that I'm using as a unique id for a  tag in HTML.  For the most part this works, until I try to access it with jQUery.  The code looks like this:

```
      var thisID = '#lesson' + String(this .model.attributes.ID);
      alert(thisID);
      $(thisID).fadeTo('slow' , 0.5);
```

The alert works just fine, but the jQuery part causes this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #lesson{35E87357-1251-4C68-A1B2-8F83A4B3E0E9}
```

What's weird is, if I remove the brackets (like, after the initial SQL call) from the GUID, so the string looks like this:

```
#lesson35E87357-1251-4C68-A1B2-8F83A4B3E0E9
```

...then it works.  But I'd rather not remove the brackets.  Also, it doesn't seem to a matter where i concatenate the string.  Any ideas how I might fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curly Braces mean that you are defining an object in JavaScript. You need to escape them with `\\` in order to use them with jQuery.

Comment: *"Curly Braces mean that you are defining an object in JavaScript."* They can mean that, but we are talking about a string here. Curly braces inside strings usually don't need any special treatment. In this case they have to be escaped because the string is used as *selector*. This has nothing to do with JavaScript syntax or objects or whatever though. I can create the string `var foo = "{42}";` without any problems.

Comment: We are talking about a string right up until jQuery uses it. At that, you get `DOM Exception 12, Error: An invalid or illegal string was specified.`

Comment: I edited my post to make it more clear that defining a string with Curlies in it is fine, but using that as a jQuery selector means escaping.

Comment: Well, yes, jQuery will parse the string or pass it to native browser methods, such as `querySelectorAll`. However, the string will **never** be evaluated as JavaScript and hence the braces don't have anything to do with object literals here. *edit:* That doesn't change the fact that your first sentence is wrong in this context. It's like saying *"You have to escape `-` because it means you are performing subtraction in JavaScript"*. That's *not* the reason why you have to escape those characters.

Answer (score 0):

The `{}` have to be escaped since they are meta characters. You can do this by using [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression:

```
thisID = thisID.replace(/[{}]/g, '\\$&');
```

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  `` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ `` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, an element with `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.